# how to remove duplicate values in sqlitedatabase?

Tags: android, android-studio

i'm developing an iun which it uploadd and retrive data from firebase and before retreiving it,store it in Sqlite database but in sqlitedatabase on every insertion,  duplicate values are inserting in Sqlitedatabase
 how to ignore duplicate values before insertion so how to solve this issue.

```
public static final int DB_VERSION =1;

public static String getDataBASE_NAME() {
    return DataBASE_NAME;
}

public static void setDataBASE_NAME(String dataBASE_NAME) {
    DataBASE_NAME = dataBASE_NAME;
}

public static  String DataBASE_NAME;


Context context;




private static final String SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES =
        "CREATE TABLE " + DocumentsReader.FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME + "(" +
                DocumentsReader.FeedEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                DocumentsReader.FeedEntry.COLUMNS_TITLE + " TEXT," +
                DocumentsReader.FeedEntry.COLUMN_SUB_TITLE + " TEXT)";



private static final String SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES =
        "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " +DocumentsReader.FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME;




public DocumentsDatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DocumentsDatabaseHelper.getDataBASE_NAME(), null, DB_VERSION);


    this.context =context;


}


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES);



}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES);
    onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);

}
```

// method for adding values in sqlitedatabase android studio

```
  public void addDocuments(String name , String Uri, DocumentsDatabaseHelper documentsDatabaseHelper){

       SQLiteDatabase db= documentsDatabaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
       ContentValues values =new ContentValues();
       values.put(DocumentsReader.FeedEntry.COLUMNS_TITLE,name);
      values.put(DocumentsReader.FeedEntry.COLUMN_SUB_TITLE,Uri);


          long rows=   db.insertWithOnConflict(DocumentsReader.FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME,null ,values,SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);

          if(rows==-1){


              Toast.makeText(context,"not inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

          }
          else{
              Toast.makeText(context, String.valueOf(rows)+"inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


          } }
```

Comment: You should show your database schema, and sample data that's giving you duplicates to be sure, but you're probably just not using a unique or primary key on the columns with duplicates.

Comment: @Shawn now you check i have added some more codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use `UNIQUE` in the `CREATE` statement of the table to identify the column(s) that you don't want to have duplicate values. So if you want to apply this property to column `DocumentsReader.FeedEntry.COLUMNS_TITLE`, use this:

```
private static final String SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES =
    "CREATE TABLE " + DocumentsReader.FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME + "(" +
            DocumentsReader.FeedEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
            DocumentsReader.FeedEntry.COLUMNS_TITLE + " TEXT UNIQUE," +
            DocumentsReader.FeedEntry.COLUMN_SUB_TITLE + " TEXT)";
```

After this change you need to uninstall the app from the device/emulator where you test it and rerun to recreate the db.

Comment: I'm glad_______

Answer (score 1):

Sqlite documentation states that if the primary key is an integer, it will be auto incremented on each new entry if not inserted explicitly.

Now since you're not explicitly setting the id in your insert statement, each insert will generate a new id thus causing each row to be considered a new row.

To avoid this, either explicitly enter the id in your cv or have a constraint like unique on one of the columns if it fits your logic .... ( Eg a unique on a name might not be logical, but a unique on say passport might be )

Comment: I don't know exactly what you're doing and what data you receive from your server, but this will guide you to where you need to go in your code/query logic